# Accessing rows PK after Insert (SqlDataSource)

Tags: c#, sqldatasource

I need to be able to get the primary key of an nserted row in C#, and so far I'm unsure how. I've put SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() into my SQL query, but how do I access this from the SqlDataSource_Inserting method, so I can store it in an auditing table? In my method I only now how to access the parameters (e.Command.Parameters)

EDIT:

My parameters are stored in my ASP.NET file like so (some extracts):

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [NominalCode] ([VAXCode], [Reference], [CostCentre], [Department], [ReportingCategory]) VALUES (@VAXCode, @Reference, @CostCentre, @Department, @ReportingCategory)"

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="VAXCode" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="Reference" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="CostCentre" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="Department" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="ReportingCategory" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </InsertParameters>
```

And I fill the parameters in C# codebehind

```
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", "Nominal");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", "Insert");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", fields);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", DateTime.Now);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it via the Command Parameters by adding a new one with a [Direction](http://System.Data.SqlDbType.Int%29;) of Output, (or you can use ReturnValue if you're not returning another result, like rows affected).

ie. Add these three rows to the end of your parameters list

```
SqlParameters pKey = new SqlParameters("@pKey", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
pKey.Direction = Output;
command.Parameters.Add(pKey);
```

Then at the end of your sql, set that parameter to the Primary Key value like so:

```
set @pKey = scope_identity();
```

ie.

```
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [NominalCode] ([VAXCode], [Reference], [CostCentre], [Department], [ReportingCategory]) VALUES (@VAXCode, @Reference, @CostCentre, @Department, @ReportingCategory); set @pKey = scope_identity()"
```

Then just read it back after you've executed the command:

```
int primaryKey = (int)pKey.Value;
```

Simples!

Another way to do auditing is to have the stored proc perform the audit capture directly, to ensure consistency and to save doing it in all the apps but this is all down to preference and system design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I'm a bit confused though, I've editted my post with details

Comment: @Chris Ok, can you put your SQL in a stored proc? It would be easier if you could

Comment: @Chris Actually, doesn't matter too much. I'll update my answer to fir your code better. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Cheers buddy, yup :) but it says I must delcare the scalar variable pKey. But I set @pKey as the value (in th INSERT query) for a field in an audit database I'm using, rather than setting it as int primaryKey - is that what is messing it up?

Comment: @Chris Sorry I had some inconsistency with my parameter naming, I had it called @pKey some places and @p_pkey in other places. I've fixed it now but check that they're all @pKey in your code, it's probably that! The int primaryKey was just the c# bit for reading it out again

Comment: Thanks again, I thought that and made sure everything was @pKey anwyay, so that isn't the cause of the error :(

Comment: Ok, and you're adding @pKey to the list of command parameters? as @pKey? Thats the only thing I can think of that it could be

Comment: Fixed it :) I wasn't declaring the parameter in the ASP.NET page. Many thanks for your help, I really appreciate it